# How to import 2 files to each other

Tags: python

I have 3 python files:

**main.py**

```
import shell
import basic

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shell.init()
```

**shell.py**

```
import main

def init():
    while True:
        global command
        command = input("")
        main.basic.interpreter()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
```

and **basic.py**

```
import main

com = main.shell.command

def interpreter():
    return com
```

When I run `main.py` it runs `shell.py` which asks for user input and then stores it in a global variable and calls the `interpreter` function  that returns the `com` varibale. But when I run it I get an error: 
`module 'shell' has no attribute 'command'`, and when I tested it again I got: `partially initialized module 'shell' has no attribute 'command' (most likely due to a circular import)`.

but when I remove the `com` variable and instead returning the `main.shell.command` (`return main.shell.command`) it works.

Is there a way to store this as a variable and what's causing the problem?
I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shell.command` doesn't get defined until `shell.__init__` gets called, but that doesn't happen until after `basic` is imported. But in order to execute `basic.py` in order to complete the import, you need `shell.command` to be defined.

You should redesign your modules so that `shell.py` and `basic.py` don't have to import `main`.

Comment: After I give it the user input I get a warning: `partially initialized module 'basic' has no attribute 'interpreter' (most likely due to a circular import)` (After the changes)

Comment: A “circular import” is when you have one module that imports another module, and this second module imports the first, in a circle. I think you’re *technically* allowed to do that but it is almost always a bad idea, and not what you want. In this case, you should refactor such that the other two modules don’t need to `import main`.

Comment: I don't understand. How can they not import `main` and also not import each other, then how to import them (That's what I understood, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: An `import` does more than you think. It executes the code in the appropriate file, uses the result to create a `module` object, then assigns that module object to a name. If two files import each other, you start executing the first, which executes the second, which starts executing the first, etc. If you structure things carefully, you can avoid issues with the seemingly infinite loop it induces, but it's far easier to make a module independent of any module it imports.